# Lanzar alertas desde un botón en header React Native

Tags: react-native

Tengo un problema tratando de lanzar una alerta desde un botón que tengo en el header, del lado derecho.

No estoy seguro de lo que me está fallando, intenté poner el método en un componentDidMount, pero me aparecen las alertas desde que inicia la app, sin haber presionado el botón.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        headerTitle: ('',
            ...
        ),

        
        headerLeft: (
            ...
        ),

        headerRight: (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this.createReport() }}>
                <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30, marginLeft: 10 }}
                source={require('./images/reportIcon.png')}
                />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    };
};

_report = ()=> {
    Alert.alert(
      //Mi lógica
    );
}
```

Comment: Muestra como tienes tu `componentDidmount`? No entiendo por qué se llama, seguro debes estar llamando de otro sitio, porque tienes dos errores notables en ese código, el primero es que al hacer `() => { this._report }` no estás llamando la función, para llamarla debería ser así: `onPress={this._report}` o `() => { this._report() }` es decir te faltan los parentesis, y el otro error, es que estás dentro de un método estático, por lo que `this` no hace referencia a tu instancia del componente y obviamente `_report` no lo reconocería

Comment: Cómo podría hacer para que lo reconozca? Mi `componentDidMount` solo tiene this._report

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un pequeño error de sintaxis y puede que por eso te este fallando al presionar el botón, y si metes la alerta en el ComponentDidMount es normal que te lo ejecute cuando carga la pagina por que después del constructor es lo siguiente que se ejecuta, en definitiva tu código deberá quedar de la siguiente manera para que te funcione.

Un saludo.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        headerTitle: ('',
            ...
        ),


        headerLeft: (
            ...
        ),

        headerRight: (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this._report() }}>
                <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30, marginLeft: 10 }}
                    source={require('./images/reportIcon.png')}
                />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    };
};

_report = ()=> {
    Alert.alert(
      //Mi lógica
    );
}
```

Lo unico que he añadido es los () a la llamda de la funcion en el onPress.
**onPress={() => { this._report() }}**